# What is the best way to connect react.js UI to my node.js API and mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, rest, api, reactjs, socket.io

I'm working on my first project and would like to know if socket.io is the only or the best solution to connect my UI to node.

Is there anything else you could recommend me? Real-time is not important, I just want to access my data. Simple keywords would already help me a lot.

Thank you!
GT

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty straightforward:

Make sure your node.js server returns (JSON) data on certain calls, e.g.

```
//this is your API endpoint
app.use('/api/endpoint', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send({
        key: 'value'
    });
});


//this sends your html file with react bundle included
//has to be placed after the api handling
app.use('*', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});
```

You don't have to serve your html with the same server, but it normally makes sense.

Now, you can make API calls inside your React app to fetch the data. I like to use axios (https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios), but you can make the calls however you want.

You should make the call and save it somehow, either in state or in your store if you use redux.

E.g.:

```
...

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://yourserver.com/api/endpoint')
        .then(function (response) {
            this.setState({
                data: response.data
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

...
```

Sending Data to your node server to store it in a DB is pretty similar.

Please note, that this is just a basic example, you will encounter some issues along the way, especially when you go to production, such as CSRF protection or JWT for securing your API. However, this should get you started!